# Adding data to comboBox in GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, combobox

I'm trying to populate a comboBox in my server GUI with some data. Specifically, i would like to add the id of the clients registered to the Server.
I must have implemented it wrong, because changes after the initialize() method of the gui don't apply.

I copy here the involved code:

**In server:**

```
public class Server implements ServerInterface {

    private static List<ClientInterface> clients;
    static ServerGui gui;
public Server() throws RemoteException
    {
        super();
        clients = new ArrayList<ClientInterface>( );
        gui = new ServerGui();
    }
*.... other methods not involved ....*
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try {
            Server statsServer = new Server();
            ServerInterface stub = (ServerInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(statsServer, 1099);

            Registry r=LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            r.rebind("aaa", stub);
            System.out.println("Server ready");
            //gui.fullCombobox(clients);
            gui.main(null);
        }
        /* If any communication failures occur... */
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("Communication error " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**In GUI**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;


public class ServerGui {

    private JFrame frame;
    public JComboBox<String> comboBox;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ServerGui window = new ServerGui();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public ServerGui() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 725, 487);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addItem("ciao");
        comboBox.addItem("miao");
        comboBox.setBounds(162, 113, 182, 38);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);

    }

    public void fullCombobox(List <ClientInterface> lista) throws RemoteException
    {
        Iterator<ClientInterface> it= lista.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            ClientInterface c = ( ClientInterface ) it.next();
            Integer i = c.getId();
            comboBox.addItem(i.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

When i invoke a Server method through Client, i invoke at the end of it the fullComboBox method too. I supposed the combobox would reload automatically, but it doesn't change at all.

It seems that all i do after the initialize() method doesn't work.

How can i resolve that?
And am i following the right way to do a gui for a Server? I had some doubts if to put a gui object inside the server (as i did) or to put a server inside the gui. I'm really confused.

Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reviewing your code shortly, it seems that you are not even calling the method

```
 public void fullCombobox(List<ClientInterface> lista) throws RemoteException {}
```

You either forgot to show the call in your code or it was the mistake that made you think that it is a problem with the JComboBox.

Comment: I wrote that i invoke it at the end of a server method called by client I call it in this way:   
gui.fullCombobox(clients);

Comment: Before you call your fullCombobox method, print out the size of the List of your ClientInterface's. I'm quite sure your list is not full of any ClientInterface's which may be the problem. Otherwise, if this isn't the case, I'll check and see if you did anything else that may have been the problem.

Comment: No, it prints the correct number, i just tried. Each client i add registers into "clients" and its size increases consequentially. I also tried to put simply some text inside the function fullComboBox, but it didn't work. That's the reason why i'm wondering why changes after initialize() have no effect :/

Comment: But it is showing "ciao" and "miao", correct?

If so, I'm sure setting the bounds is causing an issue. I'm going to look into this for a bit to see if you did anything else that may have not let it be properly done.

Comment: Yes, "ciao" and "miao", being inserted into initialize() are inside the comboBox. If you need all functions, even if they're irrelevant for this, just tell me.

Comment: Well first off, you already made an instance of ServerGui in the Server constructor. Second, you are making another instance of ServerGui in the ServerGui main. Move the code from the main method into initialize and remove the main method. There is no need for that.

Comment: OMG, i cutted and copied all code from main to initialize, removed the main (always in ServerGui) and accordingly removed the invocation of "gui.main(nll)" from the server. It started an infinte loop! I had to kill it from task manager.
That's beacause in initialize it creates another ServerGui.. Hmmm how can i fix that??

Comment: Remove whatever you added to the initialize and at the end do:

frame.setVisible(true);

Comment: Yep, it worked! Now i've only to reset the comboBox before every update to avoid repeated values and put a button to reload manually. Thank you so much!