# How to pass arguments to a gui

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm referring to the code i wrote in this question [Adding data to comboBox in GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891544/adding-data-to-combobox-in-gui) .

Now I have a Gui declared into a Server. I would like to create a button that manually updates the comboBox. My problem is that i don't know how to take data from the Server calling functions directly from GUI.

E.g. the function

```
public void fullCombobox(List<ClientInterface> lista) throws RemoteException {}
```

declared into server class can be used, always inside server class, because the gui is declared into the Server. I don't know how to do directly something like this in the GUI because i've no access to the **list** *clients*. In this case my problem is to take that list, but the problem can be extended on all the other data stored into the server.

How could i do to solve this?

Thanks in advice, I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Basically you need to retrieve a new copy of the array list clients from the server to update your jcombobox? Your problem is that you do not know how to go about it right?

Comment: Exactly, i don't know how to retrieve data from server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Server, add this

```
//...some of your code class level
clientArrayListUpdaterHelper delta;
//...moar code
public Server() throws RemoteException
{
//...more of your code
delta = new clientArrayListUpdaterHelper();
gui = new ServerGui(delta);
//...more of your code
```

Where ever you have your clients.add(), add

```
delta.setClients(clients);
```

below it

in your gui class, add this

```
//...class level code
clientArrayListUpdaterHelper clientListHere;

public ServerGui(clientArrayListUpdaterHelper alpha) {
 clientListHere = alpha;
//...more of your code till you close your constructor
```

"...button that manually updates the comboBox...". 
Basically now you need your method that is called when your button is clicked, so lets give it an arbitrary name of clientComboBoxRefresh.

```
public void clientComboBoxRefresh(java.awt.event.MouseEvent me){
 fullCombobox(clientListHere.getClients());
}
```

Now what is this clientArrayListUpdaterHelper? Well it should be like this:

```
public class clientArrayListUpdaterHelper{
 private java.util.List <ClientInterface> alpha;
public void setClients(java.util.List <ClientInterface> beta){
alpha = beta;
}
public java.util.List <ClientInterface> getClients(){
return alpha;
}
}
```

It should work, I do not know what exception will be thrown or encountered, what ever may occur handle it appropriately.  I did not write this code within an IDE but straight in this browser. And with your JComboBox I believe you should clear its contents to avoid duplication/redundant items from being added.

Comment: so you suggest to create a new class that stores data i need and that can be called by gui? I could even store other type of things in that class, as soon as i can i try and i let you know.

Comment: It worked! I called the class Storage so that i can add there other things i need to pass to gui. Thanks a lot.